# Design pattern for Staging and Production webservices

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a two web services, `ServiceReferenceStaging` and `ServiceReferenceProduction`.  A class in each web service called `OperationsClient` has a method `calculateCost` that I need to consume.

Trouble is, this method has a signature that requires types specific to that web service:

```
// staging
ServiceReferenceStaging.OperationsClient.calculateCost(
    ServiceReferenceStaging.TransactionHeaderType header,
    ServiceReferenceStaging.ExtLocationDetailsType fromAddress,
    ...

// production
ServiceReferenceProduction.OperationsClient.calculateCost(
    ServiceReferenceProduction.TransactionHeaderType header,
    ServiceReferenceProduction.ExtLocationDetailsType fromAddress,
    ...
```

Obviously the calling code doesn't care what webservice is being used - the code should work the same for staging and production, and various mapping methods that read `header` values from config and map the application's addresses into `fromAddress` should work for both the staging and production web services.

For the calling code I can wrap the two web services in concrete implementations of an interface.  But what can I do to map domain objects to `header` and `fromAddress` in a generic fashion for each concrete implementation?

Comment: Why do you have different code for staging and production?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The two web services are the API I've been provided with.

Comment: So, you're trying to call two different services, using the same consuming code, when the two services take different types as parameters?

Comment: Can't you simply delete one of the references and code against the other, using config to distinguish between your different environments?

Comment: That was what I ended up doing.  All I needed to do was update the endpoint in the config and delete a web service.  I'll answer it later if there isn't a similar answer by that point.